# Cookies null from front end but visible in postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session

Hello I am practicing jwt authentication with react js and node js

whenever user is logged in a jwt token is set in cookies as follows

***I am just matching email only not password currently focused towards maintaining sessions***

```
exports.login = async(req,res)=>{


    const u  = await User.findOne({
        where:{
            email:{
            [Op.eq]:req.body.email
        }
        }
    })
if(u!=null)
{
    
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: u.id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
    
    
const cookie = req.cookies.token;
console.log("I  am cookies",cookie) //shows token in postman but null when logged in from react frontend
if (cookie == undefined){
    
res.cookie('token', token, {httpOnly: true});


}

return res.status(200).json({"status":200,message:"login success"});

}else
{
    res.json({"status":400,"message":"Login Failed"})
}

}
```

**My check token method**

```
exports.checkToken =async(req,res)=>
{
   
    console.log("DATA ONE: ", req.cookies.token)
    const req_token = req.cookies.token
    let auth = false;
    if(!req_token)
    {
        return res.json({"message":"Login Again"})
    }
    try{
        if(!jwt.verify(req_token,process.env.JWT_SECRET))throw 'token not valid';
        else{
            auth =true;


        }


    }catch(err)
    {
            console.log("Invalid TOken")
    }

    if(!auth)
    {
        return res.json(400).json({"message":"token verification failed"})
    }else
    {
        const data = jwt.verify(req_token,process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        console.log(data)
          User.findOne({
            where:{
                id:{
                [Op.eq]:data._id}}}).then((user)=>{
                    
                    if(!user)
                    {
                        return res.status(400).json({"error":"user not found"})
                    }
                    const {id,email}=user
                    return res.status(200).json({user:{id,email}})
                })
              
                
    }
}
```

***i am using cookie-parser and have positioned it before my routes such that no conflict of order occur***

**my server.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const sequelize = require('./config/connection');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var cors = require("cors");

    var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

app.use('/students',students)
sequelize.sync();
app.listen(port,(err,res)=>{

    console.log(`connected on port number:${port}`)
})
```

***and in my routes file I am hitting my methods as follows***

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const Authcontroller = require('../controllers/Authcontroller')
router.get("/verifyToken",Authcontroller.checkToken)
router.post("/login",Authcontroller.login)
```

so for testing when I hit routes to check my login functionality and verify auth token both things work and return cookies as can be seen in images
[image: VERIFYING TOKEN]
[image: Login]

**Lastly, This is my frontEnd login function and on useEffect I am checking for the token if valid or not**

```
const isAuthenticated = ()=>
{
  
  axios.get("http://localhost:3855/students/verifyToken").then((res)=>{
console.log(res)
    setUser(res.data.user)

  })
}

React.useEffect(()=>{
  isAuthenticated()
},[])
```

and my login function

```
const login = () =>
{
    var options = {
        email:userEmail
    }
    axios.post("http://localhost:3855/students/login",options).then((res)=>{
        
        if(res.data.status == 200)
        {
            console.log("redirect to home ")
        }else
        {
            console.log("redirect to login ")
        }
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
    

    
    
}
```

***I set token properly when trying from postman and from react front end but when i retrieve it i only get it in postman not in react frontend.***

**I have tried to do in incognito and in different browser but not success there**

The response I get in react app is

```
{ message: "Login Again" }
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
BY using proxy in my front end app that is pointed towards the backend
i added
"proxy":"http://localhost:3085"

after it I deleted package-lock.json file of my frontend app along with node_modules and then installed npm install
after it when I hit url to backend a proxy was created hiding my backend url by showing front-end url
http://localhost:3855/students/login was shown as http://localhost:3000/students/login

and It worked as expected

Comment: I'm having the same problem.... do you have monolithic application ? or the front is separated from  backend

Comment: Frontend is a separate react app